# reading a text file of non-even lines into 2D array

Tags: c, arrays, 2d

Sorry I am very new to C and I'm having a hard time.  I have an input text file that reads:

```
5 3
383 386 287
415 293 335
368 492 149
421 362 27
190 59 263
```

and I am trying to read this into a 2D array.  What I am trying is this:

```
FILE * fin = NULL;
fin = fopen("myTestData.txt", "r");
int twod[MAX_ROWS][MAX_COLS];

int i, j, num, row, col;
fscanf(fin, "%d%d", &row, &col);

fclose(fin);

fin = fopen("myTestData.txt", "r");
for(i = 0; i < row; i++)
{
    for(j = 0; j < col; j++)
    {
        fscanf(fin, "%i ", &num);
    twod[i][j] = num;
    }
}
```

The problem I am having is that on the first row where the blank is (twod[0][2]) it is assigning it the value of the first integer of the second row (383).  What can I do so that [0][2] gets a null value?

Thanks for any help

Comment: You can read the input line by line, and tokenize it for numbers. If there are fewer numbers, assign dummy values to the remaining elements.

Comment: By the way, it looks like the first line specifies the number of rows and columns in the input data. That's how your code uses it (see how `row` and `col` are assigned values). So you'll simply need to start reading from the second line in your `for` loops. And there are no `null` values for ints in C.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the lines where you close and reopen the file. After you read in the number of rows and columns, you simply need to process the remaining data, which will be well structured - as are most homework problems.

```
FILE * fin = NULL;
fin = fopen("myTestData.txt", "r");
int twod[MAX_ROWS][MAX_COLS];

int i, j, num, row, col;
fscanf(fin, "%d%d", &row, &col);

//fclose(fin);

//fin = fopen("myTestData.txt", "r");
for(i = 0; i < row; i++)
{
    for(j = 0; j < col; j++)
    {
        fscanf(fin, "%i ", &num);
        twod[i][j] = num;
    }
}

for (i = 0; i < row; i++)
{
    for (j = 0; j < col; j++)
        printf("%d ", twod[i][j]);
    printf("\n");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>

    #define NUM_MAX_SIZE 20

    int** get2DArray( int rows, int columns )
    {
        int index = 0, **array = (int**)calloc( rows, sizeof( int* ) );

        for( ; index < rows ; index++ )
        {
            array[ index ] = (int*)calloc( columns, sizeof( int ) );
        }

        return array;
    }


    void print2DArray( int** matrix, int rows, int columns )
    {   
        int x = 0, y = 0;
        for( ; x < rows ; x++)
        {
            for( y = 0 ; y < columns ; y++)
            {
                printf( "%d\t", matrix[x][y] );
            }
            puts("");
        }
    }

    void freeMatrix( int** matrix, int rows )
    {
        rows--;
        for( ; rows > -1 ; rows-- )
        {
            free( matrix[ rows ] );
        }

        free( matrix );
    }

    int main()
    {
        FILE* file = fopen( "input.txt", "r" );

        int rows, columns;

        fscanf( file, "%d", &rows );
        fscanf( file, "%d", &columns );

        int x = 0, y = 0, num , **matrix = get2DArray( rows, columns );

        for( ; x < rows ; x++)
        {
            for( y = 0 ; y < columns ; y++)
            {
                fscanf( file, "%d", &matrix[ x ][ y ] );
            }
        }

        print2DArray( matrix, rows, columns );
        freeMatrix( matrix, rows );

        fclose( file );
        return 0;
    }
```